# Best way to parse the data in the below format in python to be stored in sql

Tags: python, sqlite, parsing

Sample data in a .txt file:-

```
Pamplona    ['gorasanjuan']
Halifax    ['shippingsaturdaywithlindsey']
Nottinghamshire    ['goodluck']
Eindhoven    ['ngfcompetitie', 'roadtothehoofdklasse']
Rotterdam    ['p2000']
---
---
```

1. What is the most suitable library/ap's in python to parse the data stored as in above format in .txt file to be stored in sql(using sqlite in python) or in datagrams?
2. Which one would be more preferable, storing as in sql database or storing as datagrams? 
   It would be manipulated and exported for visualization purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [re](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) to split each line into the key and the remaining list. Because the lists are quasi in a JSON format, you can use the module [json](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html) to parse them (therefore you have to replace `'` with `"`). Example:

```
import json
import re

data = dict()

with open("test.txt", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd.readlines():
        m = re.match("^(\w+)(.*)", line)
        data[m.group(1)] = json.loads(m.group(2).replace("'", "\""))

print data
```

With the file `test.txt`:

```
Pamplona    ['gorasanjuan']
Halifax    ['shippingsaturdaywithlindsey']
Nottinghamshire    ['goodluck']
Eindhoven    ['ngfcompetitie', 'roadtothehoofdklasse']
Rotterdam    ['p2000']
```

you get the output:

```
{'Rotterdam': [u'p2000'], 'Halifax': [u'shippingsaturdaywithlindsey'], 'Nottinghamshire': [u'goodluck'], 'Pamplona': [u'gorasanjuan'], 'Eindhoven': [u'ngfcompetitie', u'roadtothehoofdklasse']}
```

For the database you can also use a key-value-store like [levelDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LevelDB).